# do_shortcode by another query

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

*a bit hard to explain.*

How to use `do_shortcode` by another post query ?

**Example :**

Current post id is `1` is that possible to use `do_shortcode` from post id query `2` ?

Bacause I used a **breadcrumb** function. But some page I want to get breadcrumb from **another page**.

**I tried :**

```
query_posts('p=2');
do_shortcode('[breadcrumb]');
wp_reset_query();
```

It does not work.

Any trick ?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I forgot `while` with `the_post`

```
query_posts('p=2');
while(have_posts()):the_post();
$s = do_shortcode('[breadcrumb]'));
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
return $s;
```